# How to find more than six eigenvectors of a large matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, pca, eigenvector

I have a big matrix with size 12000x12000 and I need to find 100 eigenvectors with the highest 100 eigenvalues of that matrix (in order to perform a PCA dimension reduction).

I tried using the matlab's eig function, which returns more eigenvectors than I need takes forever since the matrix size is too big.
I also noticed that there the 'eigs' function is much faster but it doesn't returns only 6 eigenvectors, which is less than what I need.

any ideas what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the second, optional parameter to `eigs`, which controls how many eigenvectors are returned.

Comment: but then I'll only get the eigenvalues without the eigenvectors. from matlab documentation: "eigs(A,k) return the k largest magnitude eigenvalues".

Comment: @user2955997: Also use the second, optional output argument.

Comment: thanks, it works (it didn't work before, and now I understand why)